# Clearing swt.Browser cookies

Tags: java, facebook, cookies, swt

I'm using the `swt.browser` package to allow users to login with Facebook in my application. However, when a user has logged in, the session/cookie is stored on disk. My goal is to remove all sessions/cookies. Clearing the sessions through `Browser.clearSessions()` doesn't help, since the Facebook-authentication key (or similar) is most likely **stored as a cookie**.

Searching the web and the (thin) documentation for hours, I'm unable to find a way to clear the cookies for the instance.

`browser.getBrowserType()` returns "*ie*". A final resort would be to clear the whole computers cookies.

I've also tried:

```
OS.InternetSetOption(0, OS.INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SE­SSION, 0, 0);
```

Which didn't help either. *(found at*: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=85962)*

Manually clearing Internet Explorer's cookies seems to to the trick, I'm however looking for a programmatic solution.

**How to clear the browsers cookies?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem... You can remove

```
%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies
```

folder.

Comment: Many thanks for sharing your solution, this did the trick. Quite bad that it's necessary to do this manually, though.